# How can I change which master page is used for a web page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, visual-web-developer-2010

When creating a new item - "Web Form using Master Page" I get a dialog for choosing the master page.

Can I get that dialog for an existing page so I can change its master page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also change this in the .aspx page, change the MasterPageFile="" setting to whichever masterpage you want the page to use.

Comment: I actually got to the dialog through that (Through Intellisense). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can set the master page by going to the markup and adding `MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"` to the `<%@ Page` directive

Change Site.master to whatever your master page's name is

**Or**

If you're in the Page's Markup, when clicking on the `<%@ Page` directive and viewing the Properties window - you will see a `MasterPageFile` property (**Note**: this is **not** shown when clicking on the page name in the Solution Explorer)

Comment: I tried that already - I don't see a master page property there.

Comment: Updated the answer with another option, about the properties-  what visual studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Web Developer 2010. See my comment to Jeggs. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the master page in the @Page directive.